# Sending funds to someone with no bank account

Tags: money-transfer

My nephew is getting released from jail in about 30 days, and lives in another city. My brother has agreed to send him funds to obtain a living space from his account that my brother is now the executor of.

My nephew has no bank account yet.

Can someone tell me what might be the most expeditious and least exorbitant way to accomplish this? I'm thinking that a debit card would be the most convenient.

Comment: Please add a country tag as practise vary country to country

Comment: I think a prepaid card seems better tailored for this. You wouldn't need to set up another account for it. Then again, the nephew could just get a debit card with some reasonable transaction limits (and without the ability to change them on his own). But then if you wanted to take away the ability to withdraw from him, you would have to cancel the card or change the limit. With a prepaid card, you could just stop paying.

Comment: Also, I think that, out-of-jail context aside (which seems to be irrelevant in this case), the crux of this question is "How to give pocket money to someone who lives far away and has no bank account." This is a somewhat less exotic question, so you might want to look into suggestions regarding that, preferably -- as Dheer suggested -- geographically localized.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a money transfer service like Western Union or the equivalent.

Comment: Countries like Indonesia have concept of walk-in beneficiary. You transfer funds to a Bank/Branch with a code. Print a letter and send it to beneficiary. Beneficiary walks into the Branch, shows the letter and an identification, picks up the cash.

Comment: @Dheer: What do you mean by "countries like Indonesia"?

Comment: @tomasz He means countries with a large population of "unbanked", people with no checking or savings account. Many African and Latin American countries are like this. Historically, people have had to pay for access to a bank, or traditionally keep savings in hard assets, such as gold jewelry to avoid runaway inflation. In these countries people do often have access to cell phone/location-based money transfer services.